# using pthreads as a thread pool with queue?

Tags: c

I'm very new to C so sorry if this question is very off.  I have used Java executor service to make fixed thread pools and was having trouble understanding how to do something similar in C.

I learned how to create threads in c using pthreads(which seems easy enough) but I'm unsure how to create a queue that a fixed number of threads consume?  All the tutorials I have done so far either start the threads in their main statement on their own or they do it within a for loop. If I do this approach then I'll have millions of threads(1 for each work item) when all I want is 3 or 4 and have them processing a queue.

Is this possible and if so what do I need to learn?  If its not possible with pthreads, then I'm happy to use something else, I am developing on a mac and going to deploy it on linux.

Comment: do you have a particular reason to want this? creation and deleting of threads is quite effecient nowadays. Unless you have an application where this is critical (a lot of threads doing almost nothing) you should concentrate on other things (correctness, liveness, races...)

Comment: @JensGustedt I'm processing a 100GB log file and each line needs about about 5 million operations on it. I think the data will come in faster than I can process it, so I wanted to have a blocking queue and have the threads consume it. B/C the workload is so heavily I thought it would be better to control the number of threads(not doing it for thread creation/deleting efficiently but B/C my processing part is very cpu intensive).  I'm making many assumptions here(seeing things like I did in my Java programs) so please correct any false assumptions I'm making.

Comment: Your problem description sounds sufficiently complicated that it is already quite a challenge if you are not yet too experienced to get things correct in C. Try to get things right, first. Then, if you find that the perfomance is not what you expect, measure. This is the only way to know. Very often even experienced programmers don't estimate correctly where the bottlenecks of their programs are located. Thread creation *may* be a bottleneck, sometimes, but it is certainly not the first thing to look for.

Comment: @JensGustedt I understand I will follow your advice in terms of building and testing(I already have working code but its not threaded).  I am trying to do this no so much to optimize the threading aspect but as a way of flow control by using a blocking queue & having the threads process it. I am reading up on how to make a blocking queue but I lack understanding how to keep the threads alive to process the queue(I can prob. have them in an infinite loop but not sure if its a good idea). Just to clarify my intentions. I'll start with your approach first though. Thanks.

Comment: A standard approach would be to use a producer consumer model. This can be realized by using a mutex and a condition variable to do the signalling between threads.

Comment: @JensGustedt Thanks so much. I'll try my best to learn those. Thanks so much for your patience and advice so far, it has been really helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with a uniproducer/multiconsumer model reasonably easily by using condition variables. Keep in mind this is *one* architecture, others are certainly possible.

In the main thread, you simply create the queue, mutex and condition variable, then start up as many threads as you want running, pseudo-code such as:

```
glbQueue = []
glbMutex = new mutex
glbCondVar = new condvar
for i = 1 to 10:
    start thread using thrdFn
```

Next step is to add whatever workitems you need to the queue (using the mutex) and kicking the condition variable to wake up threads as needed:

```
while workitem = getNextWorkItem():
    lock glbMutex
    glbQueue.append (workItem)
    kick glbCondVar
    unlock glbMutex
```

Once all work items are done, you wait for the queue to empty, then you post some sentinel items to shut down the threads then wait for them to finish before exiting.

```
lock glbMutex
while glbQueue is not empty:
    kick glbCondVar
    unlock glbMutex.
    sleep for a bit
    lock glbMutex
unlock glbMutex.

for i = 1 to 10:
    lock glbMutex
    glbQueue.append (endWorkItem)
    kick glbCondVar
    unlock glbMutex.
    wait for any one thread to exit
exit
```

The threads that do the work are also relatively simple. First, they run in an infinite loop waiting for the condition variable to be kicked. Within that loop, they process work items until no more are available, then they go back to sleep.

Once the end work item has been received by a thread, it exits, guaranteeing that each thread gets one end item.

In other words, something like:

```
initialise
stillGoing = true
lock glbMutex
while stillGoing:
    wait on glbCondVar using glbMutex
    while stillGoing and glbQueue is not empty:
        extract workItem from glbQueue to thread local storage
        unlock glbMutex.
        if workItem is endWorkItem:
            stillGoing = false
        else:
            do the work specified by workItem
        lock glbMutex
unlock glbMutex
clean up
exit thread
```

That basically allows you to have a fixed number of threads processing items on the queue and the queue itself is protected by the mutex so that there's no contention between the worker threads or the main thread.